# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 when calling algo.trianglecount

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to follow Mark and Amy's Medium post about link prediction with NEO4J, [Link Prediction with NEO4J](https://towardsdatascience.com/link-prediction-with-neo4j-part-2-predicting-co-authors-using-scikit-learn-78b42356b44c)

Working great until I need to run the triangle detection algorithm:

```
CALL algo.triangleCount('Author', 'CO_AUTHOR_EARLY', { 
write:true,
writeProperty:'trianglesTrain', 
clusteringCoefficientProperty:'coefficientTrain'})
```

I get the following error:

```
`ERROR` Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed

Failed to invoke procedure `algo.triangleCount`: Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

As far as I can tell I have run everything else correctly (getting the same results in the python part etc.)

I was running Neo4j (enterprise) 3.5.11 when I first got the error, upgraded to 3.5.12 - still have the issue. I have the Apoc and Graph Algo plugins installed

Comment: I tried using an earlier database version - 3.5.6 following the same code and it works correctly. I assume a bug has been introduced sometime after this version...?

Comment: Check out the bug fixes in the latest release - sounds like what you're seeing is a bug: https://neo4j.com/graph-algorithms-3-5-13-0-release-notes/